# How do I get two armatures to follow?

Tags: bones

I have two seperate armatures I want to connect to eachother, CTRL-J adds the first armature to the second and the mesh still works as expected. But when I move the bones on one armature the bones on the other armature won't follow. So how could I get the bones to follow? The model is properly weight painted.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. Could you please elaborate? Do you mean that you want to link two armatures in such a way that when you move a bone on one, the same bone moves on the other?

Comment: @UncleSnail Not the same bone but the bones on the other armature that also influence the mesh

Comment: Could you maybe upload your blend file? I'm having troubles picturing what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

After you joined the two meshes, you must select in edit mode all the bones of the second armature and parent them to the "master" bone of the first armature, the one which moves all the others (choose "keep offset" option when asked to).

Comment: It seems to do something but it still doesn't move with all the other bones

Comment: You shoul explain better what bones you want to move with what bones

Comment: Alright I'll try to explain a bit better. I have a ton of bones on one armature and a ton on another one. They both influence one mesh. I want to join the two armatures together so it becomes one. When I move one armature the other armatures bones just stay in place. I want that armature's bones to move along with the other one so the bones will be in the right position when I try to pose them.

Comment: If they are joined they become one armature only. Generally there is a "master" bone to which is parented every other bone that is not parented to another. If there is no "master" you can create it or choose a bone of the first set and parent all the second set to it. Maybe if you upload your file we can understand better which can be a solution.